# Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context : Updated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am new to EF + MVC please advise

Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

I have attached the code from the repository, controller, view and the error stack trace.

**PeopleOnSite**

```
public class PeopleOnSite
{
    public string DoorName { get; set; }
    public int InductionNumber { get; set; }
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
    public string Contractor { get; set; }
    public string Trade { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TimeIn { get; set; }
    public int? HoursOnSite { get; set; }
}
```

**Repo**

```
public List<PeopleOnSite> GetRollCall()
{
    var query = (from a in context.AccessLog
            join ad in context.AccessDetailLog on a.EventID equals ad.AccessID
                join d in context.Doors on ad.ZoneID equals d.ZoneID
                join p in context.People on a.PersonID equals p.PersonID
                join w in context.Workers on p.PersonID equals w.PersonID
                join c in context.Contractors on w.ContractorID equals c.ContractorID
                join t in context.Trades on w.TradeID equals t.TradeID
                orderby a.FirstTimeIn
                select new PeopleOnSite
                {
                    DoorName = d.DoorName,
                        InductionNumber = p.InductionNumber,
                        // for anyone else that stumbles here it should be + " " +
                        PersonName = p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName,
                        Contractor = c.CompanyName,
                        Trade = t.Name,
                        TimeIn = a.FirstTimeIn,
            HoursOnSite = 10
        });
    return query.ToList();
}
```

**Controller**

```
 List<PeopleOnSite> peopleOnSite = taRepo.GetRollCall();
```

**View**

```
@foreach (var item in Model.PeopleOnSite)
{
    <tr>
            <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DoorName)
                </td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InductionNumber)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PersonName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contractor)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Trade)</td>
                <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeIn)</td>
                <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoursOnSite)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

**Error**

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Source Error: 



Line 74:                              HoursOnSite = 10
Line 75:                          });
Line 76:             return query.ToList();
Line 77: 
Line 78:             //var query = GetRollCall().Select( a => a.PersonName, context.People )


 Source File:  d:\SiteSentryWeb\SiteSentry.Data\ModelsAndRepositories\TimeAttendanceRepository.cs    Line:  76 

Stack Trace: 



[NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ConstantTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, ConstantExpression linq) +1484
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq) +88
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq) +149
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.BinaryTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, BinaryExpression linq) +122
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq) +88
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq) +149
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.BinaryTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, BinaryExpression linq) +87
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq) +88
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq) +149
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.MemberInitTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MemberInitExpression linq) +724
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq) +88
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq) +149
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input) +168
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding& binding) +159
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda) +166
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.SelectTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call) +71
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod) +47
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq) +141
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq) +88
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq) +149
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert() +50
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +563
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__a() +83
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +444
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__9() +270
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +251
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +645
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0() +84
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +416
   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +152
   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() +75
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +40
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +381
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   SiteSentry.Data.ModelsAndRepositories.TimeAttendanceRepository.GetRollCall() in d:\SiteSentryWeb\SiteSentry.Data\ModelsAndRepositories\TimeAttendanceRepository.cs:76
   SiteSentry.WebMvc.Areas.SiteSentry.Controllers.SiteController.Index() in d:\SiteSentryWeb\SiteSentry.WebMvc\Areas\SiteSentry\Controllers\SiteController.cs:53
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +101
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +434
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod() +76
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +117
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass48.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__41() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9688704
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: Can you post the declaratoin of the PeopleOnSite class?

Comment: I have added the PeopleOnSite class as requested.

Comment: Problem may be in this statement: `PersonName = p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName`, try replace  ' ' with " "

Comment: @Blacks: you sire are brilliant :0 thank you

Comment: @Backs - That comment helped me as well.  Thank you!